# PL/PGSQL. How does this loop statement work in Fibonacci example

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fibonacci (n INTEGER) 
   RETURNS INTEGER AS $$ 
DECLARE
   counter INTEGER := 0; 
   i INTEGER := 0; 
   j INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
   IF (n < 1) THEN
      RETURN 0;
   END IF; 

   LOOP 
      EXIT WHEN counter = n; 
      counter := counter + 1; 
      SELECT j, i + j INTO i, j;
   END LOOP; 
   RETURN i;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Hi everyone, I think the above code is simple but I don't understand how one line work,

```
SELECT j, i + j INTO i, j;
```

I assume that j starts from 1 and i=1  when n=1 
when N=2, j becomes 2 so that line becomes 2, 3 (i and J)

However, i =1 when n=2. What did I get wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`i` starts as 0, `j` starts as 1. When `n` = 2, two loops are performed.

Each loop, `i` gets the current value of `j`, and `j` gets incremented by the current value of `i` (before it gets assigned the value of `j`).

First loop: `i` becomes 1 (`j` is 1), and `j` becomes/remains 1: `i` (0) + `j` (1) = 1

Second loop, `i` becomes/remains 1 (`j` is still 1), `j` becomes 2: `i` (1) + `j` (1) = 2

Comment: Doesn't the "INTO,  I, J"  statements means I assumes the value for in the current loop and J becomes Ii+j?

Comment: Because both assignments are done in a single `SELECT`, the values at the time of the assignment are the same as at the start of each loop. So first loop is `SELECT 1, 0 + 1 INTO i, j` - both vars are now 1. Second one is `SELECT 1, 1 + 1 INTO i, j`. Now `i` is 1 and `j` is 2.

Comment: I am confused, In Loop 2, since J is assigned to i, why does i remain 1 since i=i+j

Comment: Thanks, I got it J does get increased by the counter, it gets increased by I+j

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT j, i + j
```

returns one row with two columns

Appending

```
... INTO i, j
```

stores the first column in variable `i` and the second in variable `j`.

So you have made two assignments in one statement.

The following pseudo-code shows what is going on:

```
col1 := j;
col2 := i + j;
i := col1;
j := col2;
```

Comment: Thanks Launrenz. Made w mistake if thinking j increase with the counter.You explaination is very clear.